# How can I access source code documents in every loaded project in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm building a Visual Studio extension, were I need to access source code files in each project in the solution, to scan and run some work on them.

I'm avoiding Roslyn because I need to work with XAML, F#, and C++ source code, as well as C# and VB.NET, and I wan't to use one platform to handle all languages and not mix and match if possible!

I want to support VS2015, VS2017, and VS2019.

And I'm using VS2019 for development.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate [dte.Solution.Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._solution.projects?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) -> [ProjectItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project.projectitems?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) -> [FileNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitem.filenames?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).

Comment: Thank you, Sergey.

I'm able to get solution and enumerate through the projects and files with DTE. Is there a way to get a CodeClass object out of this?

Comment: @omsharp You can get FileCodeModel from ProjectItem (instead of FileNames) and then inspect it for classes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitem.filecodemodel?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: Note the CodeModel API's don't apply to all project types, and you should probably be using VS 2015 to develop the extension to avoid any backwards compatibility issues.